# How to exclude the specific category result(post) using query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, blog, content-search-web-part

I’ve a blog site where 20+ categories are there.Now my requirement is using content search webpart I have to fetch some specific categories post using search query.  Only posts out of specific categories shall be displayed in a sitepage. Now all categories results are coming.. I tried to filter by category ID or name, but no success.

categories link like: blogs/Events/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?CategoryId=3

Any ideas on how to exclude the specific category using query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can do as the followings:
1. Go to SharePoint Admin Center->Search->manage search schema
2. Find a free RefinableStringXX managed property like RefinableString00
3. Map ows_PostCategory into it:
[image]

4. Wait for the online search crawl, maybe you need to wait for 24hrs
5. Go to the Content Search web part, then you can set the query string like:

   *path:"http://xxx/Blog/Lists/Posts" contentclass=STS_ListItem_Posts -RefinableString00: yourcategory* 
   [image]

Similar thread for your reference:[Searching Blogs on SharePoint Online](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/984ed270-461f-40ad-b267-952f033c3519/searching-blogs-on-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. But Can give me some idea about how to achieve the same for Mordern experience sharepoint ??

Comment: Hi Kally.. I have done all the steps what you mentioned but still I am not able to filter out the category from search results. and I am not getting CustomPostCategory in property filter section.. What to do for that ??

Comment: it should be your managed property which is mapped to ows_PostCategory(RefinableString00) instead of CustomPostCategory that I just used to test. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried the same but no luck.. Do you want me to share what I did ?

Comment: Have you tried as Step 1 to Step5?

Comment: Yes.. all the steps i already did

Comment: how long time did you change your managed property? You may need to wait 24hrs for the change.

Comment: yes.. I mapped managed property 2days back